# Installing Unix Setup for Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unix, rvm

Recently, I've been taking the Ruby on Rails online class with instructor Kevin Skoglund. I'm following along the video tutorials trying to set up my Unix. However, when I input this command **echo $PATH**. This is what shows up on my command line.

**/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/opt/sm/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/bin:/opt/sm/pkg/active/sbin.**

This prompt is completely different than what the instructor's command line displays which is:
**/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11/bin**

When I press enter I get the prompt below, 
**[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM$**

This is totally different from the instructor's tutorial.  Any suggestions of what I could be doing wrong or why this is appearing because I had been working on another Rails tutorial in the past.

Any suggestions or assistance with this prompt would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance,
Tina

Comment: could you show screenshoot of your work? your description provides information that are hard to believe ...

Answer (score 3):

You have not done anything wrong. The `$PATH` variable defines where the OS looks for executable programs on your system and is likely to be entirely different from somebody else's because systems store things in different places and people may have customisations. It looks like you've successfully installed a system wide ruby1.9.3-p194 via RVM. I don't think you have anything to worry about here.

You can use the `which` command to see where on your `PATH` the executable is found. If this returns nothing then you have a problem and need to modify the `PATH`. If it returns something then you should not have issues.

So, assuming `which rvm` shows the path to the RVM executable and the output of `ruby --version` mention 1.9.3-p194 then you have no issues.

Answer (score 0):

You obviously already have installed RVM that why you have different $PATH from you instructor if you're confused by the that fact just uninstall rvm

```
rvm remove all
rvm implode
```

reopen terminal

and you should have same $PATH what you instructor have